# I get java.lang.NullPointerException: null when I try to initialize the method in Vaadin View

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I am learning Java Spring. When I try to use a method to get data from a database, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.exam.kino.repository.SeansRepository.findAll(SeansRepository.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.exam.kino.views.ChoseNumberOfTicketsView.<init>(ChoseNumberOfTicketsView.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.exam.kino.views.KinoUI.init(KinoUI.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:776) ~[vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:218) [vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:76) [vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1602) [vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.8.3.jar:8.8.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

My method is called in the class responsible for View of Vaadin. When they try to call it in the main class for the test everything is OK.
This is my methods inside Repository class my ask is about findAll class:

```
@Repository
public class SeansRepository {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Seans findById(long id) {

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from seans where id=? ", new Object[] { id },
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Seans>(Seans.class));

    }

    public Collection<Seans> findAll() {

        Collection<Seans> seans = (Collection<Seans>) jdbcTemplate.query("select * from seans", new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Seans.class));
        return seans;
    }

    public int deleteById(long id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("delete from seans where id=?", new Object[] { id });
    }
}
```

This is how methods is called inside View class:

```
@DesignRoot
@AutoGenerated
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChoseNumberOfTicketsView extends AbsoluteLayout implements View{
    protected TextField nameTextField;
    protected TextField surnameTextField;
    protected Label menuLabel;
    protected TextField emailTextField;
    protected TextField dticketsTextField;
    protected TextField nticketsTextField;
    protected ComboBox<Seans> movieComboBox;
    private SeansRepository repository;

    public ChoseNumberOfTicketsView() {
        Design.read(this);  
        repository = new SeansRepository();
        movieComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Chose the movie");
        movieComboBox.setItems(repository.findAll());

    }
}
```

I am trying to get the list of movies and place it in ComboBox for choosing it.

I am adding a UI class where I have instance of my views:

```
@SpringUI
public class KinoUI extends UI{
    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        getPage().setTitle("Exam");
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("", new StartView());
        navigator.addView("chosenumberoftickets",  new ChoseNumberOfTicketsView());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initiate `jdbcTemplate`?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Inside class SeansRepository. Method findAll is inside this class too.

Comment: Since it appears your `jdbcTemplate` is null, please show how you instantiate it in the SeansRepository class, and also how you instantiate your SeansRepository in your Vaadin view

Comment: use the debugger to find the Nullpointer Exception.

Comment: @Tazavoo I have edited and replaced fragments of code with complete code of classes

Comment: @d2k2 I will try and write what I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for adding your view code.

The issue is that you create your `SeansRepository` yourself with the `new` keyword. Doing this, it will not be managed by Spring, so Spring will not autowire your `JdbcTemplate`.

Instead, you need to autowire your `SeansRepository` as well, try this

```
@Autowired
public ChoseNumberOfTicketsView(SeansRepository repository) {
    Design.read(this);  
    this.repository = repository;
    movieComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Chose the movie");
    movieComboBox.setItems(repository.findAll());

}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your way but now I am geting this error: `2019-08-21 14:04:59.689 ERROR 4944 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springVaadinServlet]  : Servlet.service() for servlet [springVaadinServlet] threw exception

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor ChoseNumberOfTicketsView() is undefined`

Comment: I have added my UI class with Instances of views.

Comment: Thank you. Using Spring managed views in Vaadin 8 it seems you still need to do the following (taken from https://vaadin.github.io/framework-spring-tutorial/)

1. Also annotate your UI with `@SpringViewDisplay` and add `implements ViewDisplay`
2. Remove the navigator, the Spring add-on will handle navigation
3. Annotate your views with `@SpringView(name="chosenumberoftickets")` and `@SpringView(name = "")` for the StartView.

This way, the spring add-on will create the views instead, and is able to inject the dependencies.